# Probability of single digit

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I'm stuck with this problem:

> What is the probability that the sum of two different single-digit
>   prime numbers will NOT be prime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You have $6$ pairs of different single-digit prime numbers and the sum of the numbers in $4$ pairs is not prime.

Comment: These prime numbers are: 23,25,27,35 37??

Comment: No. $2+7$, $3+5$, $3+7$, $5+7$.

Comment: Then, answer is $\frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by simply enumerating cases, since there are exactly $4$ such primes, namely $2, 3, 5, 7$. To get you started, note that $2 + 3$ is prime, but $3 + 5$ is not.